# Data shows as header with pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am reading an excel file using pandas with Jupyter . This is my data:
[image]

I want to select the columns `350`, `351`, `352` as data as opposed to headers, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow. By select them do you mean how to read only the first 3 columns? or how to select columns 350,351 and 352? Not sure what *How could I choose 350 351 and so on* means either

Comment: `df[[350, 351, 352]]`?

Comment: It is my fault. I wanna choose data 351,352.... These numbers stand for data but they are shown as titles.

Comment: My first excel row contains numbers from 351 to 2500. By using Jupyter they are shown as titles. I want to select all these numbers as one row

Comment: ah I get it, `pd.read_excel(file.xslx, header=None)` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Manakin it actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add `header=None` to your call to `pd.read_excel`